# Dynamically adding entries to sysctl

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, sysctl

Consider this code:

```
int procmon_state = 0;
static struct ctl_table_header *procmon_table_header;

static ctl_table state_table[] = {
    {
        .procname = "state", .mode = 0666,
        .proc_handler = &proc_dointvec_minmax,
        .data = &procmon_state, .maxlen = sizeof(int),
        .extra1 = "\x00\x00\x00\x00" /*0*/, .extra2 = "\x01\x00\x00\x00" /*1*/
    },
    { 0 }
};

static ctl_table procmon_table[] = {
    {
        .procname = "procmon", .mode = 0555,
        .child = state_table
    },
    { 0 }
};

procmon_table_header = register_sysctl_table(procmon_table);
```

This will create an entry in `/proc/sys` (so I could then just `sysctl procmon.state=1`).

My question is: Once that entry is created, how can I add more entries?

EDIT: More entries inside `procmon`, that is. For example, `procmon.another_state`

Comment: May be `register_sysctl_paths` helps here?

Comment: I would look at `proc_create_data()`.

Comment: Indeed, ```register_sysctl_paths``` might help. I'll have a look at it, thank you!  On the other side, ```proc_create_data``` it too recent (3.10+ only), even if I wish I couldn't use it.

Comment: The above source code should be added inside the sysctl.h file right?

Comment: @SowndaryaK this is part of your kernel module code

Comment: Please let me know where exactly I should add(module name)?

Comment: @SowndaryaK https://github.com/alexandernst/monks/blob/9e7dd7c3f53cb58b64d9dbff0ec8c2beb775b034/monks_kmodule/control.c#L57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no functions for changing sysctl tables in [sysctl.h](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/sysctl.h).

You have to list all entries that you might need *before* calling `register_sysctl_table`.

If you really need to change the table afterwards, you have to call `unregister_sysctl_table` before doing your modifications, and then register it again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, just look into the linux kernel's drivers directory for many examples.   Essentially, you just need to call register_sysctl_table() multiple times, for for each call you make, you will be creating a branch off an existing branch.

The details are covered here:

https://tthtlc.wordpress.com/2016/05/26/how-to-add-new-entries-to-sysctl-with-the-same-root/